# Update Table's rows based on another table'rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have 2 tables SQL Server(Tab1,Tab2)

Tab1 has

```
col1
col2 
col3
```

Tab2 has

```
col11
col22 
col33
```

I want to copy data form

col1 into col11, 
and col2 into col22.

if col3 equal to col33.

How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: provide some sample details of the table and expected output.....

Comment: You wants to copy data or update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Join the tables Based on col3 = col33 and Update the other columns.

```
UPDATE T2
    SET
       col11 = T1.col1,
       col22 = T1.col2
    FROM Tab1 T1
       INNER JOIN Tab2 T2
          ON T2.col33 = T1.col3
```

Comment: Seems like he wants to concat columns, not just change values. Don't wanna post similar query again :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to just select column values from Tab2 and insert in Tab1 as below:

```
INSERT INTO Tab2 (col11,col22,col33) 
SELECT T1.col1,T1.col2,T1.col3 
FROM Tab1 T1
WHERE T1.col3 EXISTS IN(SELECT col33 FROM Tab2 WHERE col33=T1.col3)
```

Comment: You Are inserting new rows and the requirement is to update the records by Matching col33

Comment: Actually question says : I want to copy data form.... But question title is different

Comment: Yes, From Col1 to Col11 and Col2 to Col22 IF COL3 = COL33. Which Means there is value in COL33